# Didn't understand the solution of the proof of supremum of set of positive rationals whose squares are less than 2

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I was solving the book "Problems in mathematical analysis 1" , but I couldn't understand some lines of the solution, which I have given below.

Show that $sup\{x\in \mathbb{Q}^+:x^2<2\}= \sqrt{2}$

The given solution was

Let $A= \{x\in\mathbb{Q}^+: x^2<2\}$ and let $s= sup A\,\,$.

We may assume that $s>1$.
We will now show that for any positive integer $n$,
\begin{align}
\left(s-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^2\leq 2\leq \left(s+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^2 \hspace{1 cm}(1)
\end{align}

Since $s-\dfrac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound of $A$, there exists $x^*\in A$, such that $s-\dfrac{1}{n}<x^*$. Hence
$$\left(s-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^2<(x^*)^2<2$$

Assume that $\left(s+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^2<2$. If $s$ were rational, then $s+\dfrac{1}{n}\in A$ and $s+\dfrac{1}{n}>s$, which would contradict the fact that $s= supA$.

If $s$ were irrational then, $w= \dfrac{[(n+1)s]}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ is a rational number such that $s<w<s+\dfrac{1}{n}$. Hence $w^2<\left(s+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)<2$ and $w\in A$, a contradiction.

So we have proved that $\left(s+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)2\geq2$. By the left hand side of the (1),

$s^2-\dfrac{2s}{n}<s^2-\dfrac{2s}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\leq2$, which gives$\dfrac{s^2-2}{2s}<\dfrac{1}{n}$. Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we get $s^2-2\leq0$. As above, the right-hand side of (1) gives $\dfrac{s^2-2}{3s}\geq -\dfrac{1}{n}$, which implies $s^2-2\geq 0$. therefore, $s^2= 2$.
\

The lines which I didn't understand are

Why and how initially they assumed $s>1$?

I didn't understand how the expression for $w$ that is
for $s$ be irrational, $\dfrac{[(n+1)s]}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ is rational?

Comment: As for the assumption that $s > 1$, see that $\left( 1.1 \right)^2 < 2$ so that $s \geq 1.1 > 1$.

Comment: $w$ is rational because the first term is $p/q$ and the other is $1/q$. They have used the greatest integer function.

Comment: Didn't get that actually. What if we pretend for a moment we don't know $s= \sqrt{2}$ then why shouldn't we go for numbers less than 1 initially? For example, $(0.9)^2<2$

Comment: Why did they used $n+1$, I mean they could have used only $[s]$ which is an integer and hence rational also?

Comment: Yes, you can go for lesser numbers than $1$ initially. But, you also notice at the same time that $1^2 = 1 < 2$, so that the number $1$ belongs to your set. Then, you ask the question: "Are there any more rational numbers *greater than* $1$ whose square is still less than $2$"? And the answer is yes! In particular, $1.1$ is one such number that comes to my mind. Maybe you can think of some other number!

Comment: They wanted to get a number between $s$ and $s + \dfrac{1}{n}$. That is why specifically they took $w = \dfrac{\left[ \left( n + 1 \right)  s \right]}{n + 1} + \dfrac{1}{n + 1}$.

Comment: ooh thanks! and one more thing i want to ensure, does $x^*$ means $x\neq0$ by any chance, which I said in analogy to the notation used in sets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123240/discussion-between-aniruddha-deshmukh-and-subham-248).